# Допустимо ли писать даты, года в тексте цифрами?

Tags: грамотная-речь, числительные, оформление-текста

В художественном тексте, разговорная речь. Или же строго словами?

1. В то время я работал на предприятии младшим научным сотрудником. Но карьера у меня там не сложилась из-за переезда в начале 2010 года. / или в начале две тысячи десятого года?
2. Мой дядя как-то рассказывал, что его дочь еще до января 2022-го работала в детском саду. / или ещё до января две тысячи двадцать второго?
3. Жаль, что мой приятель погиб в аварии ещё в 1995 году. / или ещё в тысяча девятьсот девяносто пятом году?

Comment: Можно посмотреть здесь  https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/pismovnik/kak-pravilno-zapisat-datu

Comment: Числительные в ХУДОЖЕСТВЕННОМ тексте   https://ficbook.net/readfic/11653699/29935568  Писать цифры числом предпочтительно в следующих случаях (перечислены 4 случая):  1. Когда требуется имитировать документы, письма, вывески, поскольку пропись в них маловероятна и будет нарушать их «подлинность». Напр.: «Будьте сегодня в 7 часов в беседке у ручья"(записка Дубровского).  И т. д.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Достоевского все цифры - словами, и вообще так милее сердцу художественного текста.

Но сейчас допустимо (и обратное смотрелось бы дико) цифры писать цифрами: даты, номера телефонов, индексы и даже 451 градус по Фаренгейту,

однако я била по лапам юных журналисточек, пишущих в заметках "сделать 10 шагов, в 5 метрах от, 4-й дом от угла", - достаточно примеров?

Answer (score 1):

Год, дату месяца, длинные числа, номера домов, телефонов и т.п. пишут цифрами.

А вот количество (восемь человек) и выражения вроде "третий человек слева", "вторая попытка" и др. пишут буквами.

Месяц в датах чаще пишут буквами (33 февраля 2077 г.), но и цифры не будут ошибками (33.02.2077 г.), просто они воспринимаются как более "технические" и выпадают из художественного текста.