# Даты в прямой речи

Tags: числительные, прямая-речь

Допустимо ли в прямой речи дату писать цифрами?

— Мария Сидорова, когда вы родились? — спросил он.

— 25 марта 1990 года, — ответила она, слегка нахмурившись.

Или требуется всё же

— Двадцать пятого марта тысяча девятьсот девяностого года, — ответила она, слегка нахмурившись.

Comment: Рекомендация Грамоты  ответы справочной службы вопрос №230915 https://gramota.ru/spravka/vopros/230915 В изданиях художественной и близкой ей литератур рекомендуется все числительные писать прописью, поскольку цифры придают тексту деловой вид.  Но есть исключения.  Цифра:  Когда стремятся подчеркнуть (иногда иронически) особую точность чисел.  Возможно, здесь именно этот случай.

Comment: Такая же  тема  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/478817/Допустимо-ли-писать-даты-года-в-тексте-цифрами

Comment: Вижу, хотя чёткого ответа и там дано не было.

Comment: Здесь подчеркивается документальная точность, лучше оставить цифру.

Comment: Правильнее вообще избегать цифр в начале предложения. Можно, но сдвинув внутрь: *Родилась 25 марта 1990-го*.